# react-native "In this environment the sources for assign must be an Object" error with RNSwipeout

Tags: react-native, typeerror

I have look at a couple of places and have tried a few workarounds but none of them worked either.
With the following Code (A Flatlist with Swipeout to delete Listelements):

```
    <FlatList data = {this.state.needList}
                refreshing = {this.refreshing}
                onRefresh = {this.refreshItems.bind(this)}
                renderItem = {({item, index}) => {

                  let swipeoutBtns = [
                    {
                      text: 'Delete',
                      backgroundColor: 'red',
                      onPress: () => {
                        console.log(this.itemsRef.child(this.state.needList[index].key));
                        this.itemsRef.child(this.state.needList[index].key).remove();
                        this.getItems(this.itemsRef);

                      }
                    },
                  ];

                  return(
                    <Swipeout right = {swipeoutBtns}
                              autoClose = {true}>
                      <View style = {[styles.flatListCss,
                                      {backgroundColor: index %2 == 0 ? '#dbdbdb' : 'white'}]}>
                        <Text style = {styles.flatListCssText}>{item.item}</Text>
                        <Text style = {styles.flatListCssText}>{item.amount}
                          <Text style = {styles.flatListCssText}> {item.value}</Text>
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                  </Swipeout>
                  );

                }}>
      </FlatList>
```

I get the following Error message:
"TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object."

I have followed the example from here: https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout

For some reason it doesn´t work for me.
A fix would be perfect. A workaround would be great as well.

Thanks ahead!